# How to chain async actions and wait for the result without store.dispatch

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to write my `INITIALIZE` action which should chain some async actions together in the following way

1. Call the initialize action.
2. Call two async actions simultaneously.
3. Wait for the completion of above actions.
4. Run additional one action.
5. Finish initialization.

here is the redux flow that I expect

`INITIALIZATION_STARTED` => `ASYNC_ACTION_A_STARTED` AND `ASYNC_ACTION_B_STARTED` => `ASYNC_ACTION_A_FINISHED` AND `ASYNC_ACTION_B_FINISHED` => `ASYNC_ACTION_C_STARTED` => `ASYNC_ACTION_C_FINISHED` => `INITIALIZATION_FINISHED`

I managed to achieve that flow using `store.dispatch` inside my epic, I know that this is anti-pattern and it will be removed in the 1.0.0 version so I would like to know how I can do it using pure epics

My working solution

```
export const initEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<Action>, store) =>
  action$.filter(actions.initialization.started.match)
    .switchMap(action => (
      Observable.forkJoin(
        waitForActions(action$, actions.asyncA.done, actions.asyncB.done),
        Observable.of(
          store.dispatch(actions.asyncA.started(action.payload)),
          store.dispatch(actions.asyncB.started(action.payload)),
        )
      ).map(() => actions.asyncC.started(action.payload))
    )
  );

const waitForActions = (action$, ...reduxActions) => {
  const actionTypes = reduxActions.map(x => x.type);
  const obs = actionTypes.map(type => action$.ofType(type).take(1));
  return Observable.forkJoin(obs);
}
```

I have also been trying to use `forkEpic` from this [comment](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/33#issuecomment-239329023) like that

```
export const initEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<Action>, store) =>
  action$.filter(actions.initialization.started.match)).mergeMap(action =>
    forkEpic(loadTagsEpic, store, actions.asyncA.started(action.payload))
      .concat(
        forkEpic(loadBranchesEpic, store, actions.asyncB.started(action.payload))
      )
      .map(() => actions.asyncC.started(action.payload))
  );
```

but it doesn't dispatch starting actions `ASYNC_ACTION_A_STARTED` and `_ASYNC_ACTION_B_STARTED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `merge` is perfect for this. You'll start listening for `asyncA.done` and `asyncB.done` and then while waiting you'll kick off the requests by emitting `asyncA.started` and `asyncB.started`. These two streams are merged together as one, so it happens in the correct order and the actions emitted by either are emitted by our epic without needing `store.dispatch`.

```
const initEpic = action$ =>
  action$.filter(actions.initialization.started.match)
    .switchMap(action => (
      Observable.merge(
        waitForActions(action$, actions.asyncA.done, actions.asyncB.done)
          .map(() => actions.asyncC.started(action.payload)),
        Observable.of(
          actions.asyncA.started(action.payload),
          actions.asyncB.started(action.payload),
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Here is a JSBin demoing: https://jsbin.com/yonohop/edit?js,console

It doesn't do any of the `ASYNC_ACTION_C_FINISHED` and `INITIALIZATION_FINISHED` stuff because code for that was not included in the question so not sure what it would have done.

You might notice this is mostly a regular RxJS question where the items streaming *happen* to be actions. This is really helpful because when you ask for help you can ask from the entire RxJS community if you craft the question as generic RxJS.

---

Note that I listened for done before starting; this is generally a best practice in case `done` is emitted synchronously after `started`. If you didn't listen first, you'd miss it. Since it's async it doesn't matter, but still generally a best practice and helpful when you unit test.

Comment: Thank you. It took me a while to understand why you didn't need to use `store.dispatch` inside merge. I didn't know that forkJoin doesn't return anything until all observables all resolved. That's why my actions weren't dispatched without `store.dispatch`.
You are right, I forgot to add entire code with `ASYNC_ACTION_C_FINISHED` and `INITIALIZATION_FINISHED`, sorry for that. Fortunately it's very similar to this so I think that I can handle it right now