# forkEpic, redux-observable 1.0.0-alpha.2, typescript

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable, rxjs6

I have one epic

```
type GetRailwaysEpic = Epic<GetRailwaysActions, AppState>;

const getRailwaysEpic: GetRailwaysEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(getRailways.request)),
    switchMap(a =>
      getRailways(state$.value.mileages.filters.date)
        .then(getRailways.success)
        .catch(getRailways.failure)
    )
  );
```

when I call anywhere actions.getRailways.request() it works as expected (REQUEST action first, SUCCESS of FAILURE next)

I have another epic

```
const initEpic: Epic<FiltersActions, AppState> = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(init)),
    switchMap(({ payload: { date, depotId, locTypeId, railwayId } }) =>
      of(selectDate(date)).pipe(
        concat(
          forkEpic(getRailwaysEpic, state$, getRailways.request())
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

my ForkEpic function:

```
function forkEpic<T extends Action, S>(
  epicFactory: Epic<T, S>,
  state$: StateObservable<S>,
  ...actions: T[]
) {
  const actions$ = ActionsObservable.of(...actions);
  return epicFactory(actions$, state$, null);
}
```

What I want: 'init' action -> 'selectDate' action -> 'getRailways.request' action -> 'getRailways.success' | 'getRailways.failure' action

What I see: 'init' action -> 'selectDate' action -> 'getRailways.success' | 'getRailways.failure' action

'getRailways.request' action's missing somewhere.
What I do wrong?

P.S. getRailways - is a function which returns promise
P.P.S. I've found similar question here [How to chain async actions and wait for the result without store.dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000384/how-to-chain-async-actions-and-wait-for-the-result-without-store-dispatch)
But it's not what I'm actualy looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that the `forkEpic` function is invoking `getRailwaysEpic` locally and because it is using `switchMap` it is swallowing a "request" action thus preventing it to reach the epicMiddleware.

The best solution is to concat "select" action with "request" action streams and return it so it is correctly propagated by epicMiddleware back to the store and then it will be intercepted and handled by `getRailwaysEpic` from the action$ stream.

Here is the working solution in the code-sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/375z2qwv1

Here is the responsible code:

```
const requestEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(a => a.type === 'request'),
    switchMap(a => from(makeRequest()).pipe(map(success)))
  );

const initEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(a => a.type === 'init'),
    concatMap(a => of(select(), request()))
  );

const rootEpic = combineEpics(requestEpic, initEpic);
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic);

// 1
// store.dispatch(init());
// should be:
// init -> select -> request -> success

// 2
// store.dispatch(request());
// should be:
// request -> success
```

Comment: What I want here - is to use 2 epics independantly, I mean, to have opportunity to dispatch both actions (request and init). If I'll use concat, I'll get infinite loop.

Comment: @abdurahmanus I have adapted answer to show the proper way of achieving what you are looking for, IMO your `forkEpic` function in the original question is not needed, adding unnecessary abstraction where correct approach would be to let the flow of epic go back to the store and then be emitted through epicMiddleware and initialize another epic that is listening for request action

Comment: Thanks, it works! I Just wanted to find out a way to combine several epics similar to redux-thunk. Maybe I need to reconsider the way I used to think.

Comment: @abdurahmanus definitely you need to, I was also switching from redux-thunk so for me the biggest difference is to think that epics are always separated so you do not refer from one epic to another directly but you return action and this action will get to another epic and switch it on. PS:  Please accept the answer